# Typescript: TS2339: Property 'faillogout' does not exist on type '{ failed(): void; onSubmit(): void; }'

Tags: typescript, vue.js

I'm using a Vue.js app with typescript and I'm getting this error:

```
Property 'faillogout' does not exist on type '{ failed(): void; onSubmit(): void; }'.
    101 |     failed () {
```

This is the script part of my .vue file

```
<script lang="ts">
import store from '../store'
export default {
  data () {
    return {
      email: '',
      password: '',
      faillogout: false
    }
  },
  methods: {
    failed () {
      if (!store.state.idToken) {
        this.faillogout = true
      }
    },
    onSubmit () {
      const formData = {
        email: this.email,
        password: this.password
      }
      console.log(formData)
      store.dispatch('login', {email: formData.email, password: formData.password})
      setTimeout(this.failed, 3000)
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

Any idea how this can be fixed please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try wrapping your component with defineComponent() to allow TypeScript to properly infer types

```js
import { defineComponent } from 'vue'

export default defineComponent({
  data() {
   return {
      email: '',
      password: '',
      faillogout: false
    }
  },
})
```